# How to add a UISplitViewController as a subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to add UISplitViewController as a subview to my ViewController when I clicked a button in it. Its not working properly.

Is it the right way to do?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't do this. According to Apple's docs, a UISplitViewController should only be the root view controller of the window.

Comment: @rdelmar So, if I need a view before showing UISplitViewController. What should I do?

Comment: Display the other view modally with the `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` presentation style.

Comment: @ChrisWagner Do you mean that, UISplitViewController will remain as root view and during the view load we have to present a view modally? Do we have anyother alternate?

Comment: You could set the root view to your other view controller and then once you are done with it, set the root view to the split view controller. Otherwise you could play with multiple UIWindows. Both can be hairy but it's the best approach I've found. I presume you want a login screen before the split view is shown?

Comment: @ChrisWagner Thanks. You are exactly right, I need a login screen before. If you can provide your comment as answer with some sample code, so that it would very much useful me and also it could be a better reference point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering based on comment discussion...

You could set the root view to your other view controller and then once you are done with it, set the root view to the split view controller. Otherwise you could play with multiple UIWindows. Both can be hairy but it's the best approach I've found.

Some pseudo code.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[CWDLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CWDLoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Now I would probably either make a delegate for the login view controller or use notifications, something to tell your app delegate that it needs to change `self.window.rootViewController` to your `UISplitViewController`

```
- (void)loginDidFinish {
    CWDSplitViewController *splitViewController = [[CWDSplitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CWDSplitViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
}
```

If you are using storyboards than you can use

`[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyIdentifier"];`

in lieu of

`[[CWDLoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CWDLoginViewController" bundle:nil];`